# Selenium IDE type="date" field won't type

Tags: selenium-ide

Im using Seleniums IDE to format a test for our web scanning environment.

On the first page, are two input fields, one for a start and one for an end date like so;

```
<input class="form-control" name="start_date" id="start-date" style="height:49px" value="2018-05-30" min="2018-05-30" max="2018-06-29" type="date">
```

For some reason, no command will type into this field, sendkeys, type, editcontent. None of them. Is there a certain way I have to format IDE to have it affect this field?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look a this, using Selenium 3.5.8 in Chrome today, I can:

```
type || id=start-date || YYYY-MM-DD
```